# i can't inject data from Json into html with angularjs using node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, http

I can't manage to inject data from a Json file into my html.
I get a good response, I can log it into chrome  [console.log of my response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcykm.png)

but i can't inject it in my html.

here is my angularJs code :

```
 <p ng-bind-html="essaiJson.titre"></p>


var app = angular.module('monApp', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('monControl', function($scope, $http, $compile){

    $scope.maVariable = "MEAN Stack";


    $http.get('/JavaScript/mean.json')
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.essaiJson = response.data;
        console.log($scope.essaiJson);
    });
```

when I log $scope.essaiJson.titre I get a good response, but when I bind it there is nothing !

my node.js code :

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/ex11.html');
});

http.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<p>{{essaiJson.titre}}</p>`

instead of `<p ng-bind-html="essaiJson.titre"></p>`

Comment: I simply put the div with the ng-repeat out of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

**ng-bind-html** evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way.

In your case, you just need to bind the json data into your html, which can be done using

```
<p>{{essaiJson}}</p>
```

Here is an example of what you are trying to acheive:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-cuhtns

Comment: thanks, it doesn't work, i think it's because i use node js and angularjs $http.get